# Problems accessing type of Base class within a typescript mix-in

Tags: typescript, mixins

I have some ES6 mixin code which looks like:

```
function DeserializableMixin(Base) {
  return class extends Base {
    deserialize(structure) {
      Object.assign(this, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(structure)));
      return this;
    }
    clone() {
      const c = this.constructor;
      return new c().deserialize(this);
    }
  };
}
```

and this works with existing code like this:

```
class FooEntity {}

class DeFoo extends DeserializableMixin(FooEntity) {}

const df = new DeFoo();
const x = df.deserialize({ bar: 43 });
const y = df.clone();
```

I would like to port this mixin to TS and based on the docs at: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#support-for-mix-in-classes it seemed reasonably straightforward.

I would like deserialize to be somewhat type safe and take a `Partial<Base>` rather than`Partial<any>` or `Partial<{}>` so that the IDE/compiler can pickup deserializations which do not match the shape of the Base class.

likewise I don't want to use `Partial<this>` as this causes functions on the derived class (e.g. clone() and deserialize()) to be allowed as a valid part of the structure.

What I want to write is this:

```
export type Constructor<T> = new(...args : any[]) => T;

export function DeserializableMixin<T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base : T) {
  return class extends Base {
    deserialize(structure : Partial<Base> ) {
      Object.assign(this, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(structure)));

      return this;
    }

    clone() {
      const c = this.constructor as Constructor<this>;

      return new c().deserialize(this as Base);
    }
  };
}
```

But typescript does not allow me to use Base as a class type, even though it does allow me to use it in the extends clause.

The only way I have come close to it is by doing the following:

```
export function DeserializableMixin<P, T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base : T, proto : P) {
  return class extends Base {
    deserialize(structure : Partial<P> ) {
      Object.assign(this, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(structure)));

      return this;
    }

    clone() {
      const c = this.constructor as Constructor<this>;

      return new c().deserialize(this as any as P);
    }
  };
}
```

which requires me to use the mixin like this:

```
class Foo {
  bar : number;
  baz : string;
};

class DeFoo extends DeserializableMixin(Foo, Foo.prototype) {}

const df = new DeFoo();
const x = df.deserialize({bar: 43})
const y = df.clone();
```

which does the job but seems a bit stupid to me. Is there a less convoluted way of doing this?

**EDIT**

I have subsequently found that even this is not enough. It is fine if the use of the mix-in remains in the same module as which the mix-in is defined, but if I export type definitions for this and use it in another module things such as:

```
const df = new DeFoo();
const df2 = df.clone();
```

do not work as intended as `df2` will have an `any` type. Note that if it is done in the same module (the module the mix-in is defined) df2 will have the type DeFoo.

In order to work around this I have added yet more seemingly redundant code.

```
export function DeserializableMixin<P, T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base : T, proto : P) {
  return class extends Base {
    deserialize<E>(this : E, structure : Partial<P> ) : E {
      Object.assign(this, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(structure)));

      return this;
    }

    clone<E>(this : E) : E {
      const c = this.constructor as any;

      return new c().deserialize(this as any as P);
    }
  };
}
```